# Adding a random number to each element in an array

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">


<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>The Lord of the Rings - Game</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>

<body>


    <div id="game-container">

        <h1>Battle!</h1>


        <div id="counters">
            <div id="total-score"></div>
            <div id="target-score"></div>
        </div>


        <div id="images-container">
            <img src="assets/images/Aragorn.jpeg" alt="Aragorn" class="LOTR-characters" id="character1">
            <img src="assets/images/Legolas.jpeg" alt="Legolas" class="LOTR-characters" id="character2">
            <img src="assets/images/Gimley.jpeg" alt="Gimley" class="LOTR-characters" id="character3">
            <img src="assets/images/Gandalf.jpeg" alt="Gandalf" class="LOTR-characters" id="character4">
        </div>

        <div id="wins-losses">
            <h2>Wins and losses go here</h2>
        </div>

    </div>



    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/javascript/game.js"></script>
</body>

</html>


var targetNumber;

var numbersAdded = [];

numbersAdded.push(char1 = $("#character1"));
numbersAdded.push(char2 = $("#character2"));
numbersAdded.push(char3 = $("#character3"));
numbersAdded.push(char4 = $("#character4"));


// Create a function that gives a random number between 1 - 12 
// and assigns it to a variable
function randomNum() {
var randomNumber = Math.floor( Math.random() * 12 ) + 1;
    console.log("Random number between 1 & 12 is: " + randomNumber);
    return randomNumber;
}

randomNum();

// loop through items in array and assign random number 
for (i = 0; i < numbersAdded.length; i++) {
    numbersAdded[i] =+ randomNum;
}
```

Im trying to add a random number to each element in the array numberAdded.  Each element is actually an img in the html that i assigned variables to and pushed to the array.

Is it possible to loop through that array and assign each image a random number which i can get on click?  Or do i have to do this 1 by 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an click handler, running it works but there are no images. You can still click on them.

```js
$(".LOTR-characters").click(function() {
  console.log(this.alt + ' scored ' + randomNum());
});

function randomNum() {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor( Math.random() * 12 ) + 1;
    return randomNumber;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="assets/images/Aragorn.jpeg" alt="Aragorn" class="LOTR-characters" id="character1">
<img src="assets/images/Legolas.jpeg" alt="Legolas" class="LOTR-characters" id="character2">
<img src="assets/images/Gimley.jpeg" alt="Gimley" class="LOTR-characters" id="character3">
<img src="assets/images/Gandalf.jpeg" alt="Gandalf" class="LOTR-characters" id="character4">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map to add a random number to each element of an array.

```
numbersAdded = numbersAdded.map(n => n + (Math.floor( Math.random() * 12 ) + 1))
```

But I am not quite sure what you want to do to the images. If you want to use jQuery to mod each image

```
$(".LOTR-characters").each(function() {
    $(this) //Is a jQuery object that can manipulate the image.
})
```

Comment: When i do that it returns -  ["[object Object]11", "[object Object]7", "[object Object]5", "[object Object]1"] in the console.

Comment: Also,  what is n => n  ?

Comment: n => n is an arrow function, the same as function(n) { return n + (Math.floor( Math.random() * 12 ) + 1) }

Comment: Tell me how you want to mod the image and I will edit the answer

Comment: Im trying to assign a random number to each image (4 images in total).  The goal is to add the image numbers together to try and reach a target number.  If i match the target number you win,  if i go over then you lose

Comment: I really don't understand what you mean by add a random number to an image

Comment: When you click the image it returns a number.  Each image will have a random number